# i want to delete data from firebase by using longclick on the listview item

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

here i add on long click listener and i want that item that i selected by long click is deleted from firebase after clicking to yes button and fire also remove from arraylist but here my app stop working after click on yes please help me to shot out from this problem

```
ListOfFiles.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



            final String deleteditem=(String) ListOfFiles.getItemAtPosition(position);

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(FetchFiles.this);
            builder.setTitle("Do You Want To Delete File ..? ");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    try
                    {
                        mRef.child(ID).child(deleteditem).removeValue();

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(FetchFiles.this, (CharSequence) e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });
            builder.show();

            arrayAdapter.remove(deleteditem);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;

        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay . So what is the question here ? Where did you stuck Exactly ? Your question is Vague Right now. Please Read [ask] and Edit your question with proper details.

Comment: now i edit it and i explain what exactly the situation please help me

Comment: Stack Overflow is an incredibly inefficient interactive debugger, so you will have to do that yourself and then report what happens. So put a breakpoint on `mRef.child(ID).child(deleteditem).removeValue();` and run the app in the debugger. Does the code get triggered? If so, are the values of `ID` and `deleteditem` what you expect them to be? If so, are there any error messages in the logcat output after this line? If none of these help, try to reproduce the problem with hard-coded values. That allows you to know if the problem is in the code that deals with the UI, or in the database code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Value Event Listener instead of an OnClick method, something like this (works for me):

```
ValueEventListener deleteListItem = new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            Firebase Ref.removeValue();
                            Toast.makeText(class.this, "Item deleted...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            arrayList.remove(position);
                            arrayAdapter.remove(arrayAdapter.getItem(position));
                            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }//onDataChange

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }//OnCancelled
                    };
Firebase Ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(deleteListItem);
dialog.dismiss();
                }//OnClick
            }).setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }//OnClick
            });
            alert.show();
            return true;
        }//OnItemLongClick
    });
```